# how to setup write permission on App_data in IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I need to setup a site to work with a local IIS 7 server (running windows 7). And I get a permissions error stating that I should setup write permission on the App_Data folder.

Where do I do this? Do I do this through IIS 7 management, or windows explorer?

**url I used for default asp.net website project:**

http://localhost:10000/Account/Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

User does not have permission to perform this action.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User does not have permission to perform this action.

```
Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

    Stack Trace:

    [SqlException (0x80131904): User does not have permission to perform this action.]
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +6277312
       System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +412
       System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1363
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +53
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6292062
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6291977
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +352
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +506
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +49
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +6293782
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +78
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +1922
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +89
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6296606
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +300
       System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +150
       System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +4603263
       System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status) +2858
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser() +412
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs e) +226
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +586
       System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +52
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3691
```

Comment: This looks like a DB connection problem - check that first.

Comment: It is a db connection problem caused by permissions. Note how I do not have permission to perform certain actions in the stack trace

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and identified what type of DB access is taking place when it fails? It could be your DB connection string.

Comment: This is the default web site project from vs 2010. It should work with no changes.

Comment: It also uses an sql lite or express database. Just has the .mdf in app_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to setup the site to use application pass-through, and then change the application pool to use NetworkService.

Comment: This disables the IIS AppPool isolation security in newer IIS versions which runs each AppPool with its own user account so it cannot write to other AppPools AppData folders. So **this is not recommended**.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer for IIS 7.5+ (Windows Server 2008) is to allow write by the group "IIS_IUSRS".  I believe this group even incorporates the IIS 8+ AppPool users, so its a much more durable way to ensure write access to App_Data

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot> icacls App_Data /grant IIS_IUSRS:M
processed file: App_Data
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\inetpub\wwwroot>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application pool uses **ApplicationPoolIdentity** which is recommended and default you need to grant permissions to **IIS AppPool\*YourAppPoolName***.

See also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Note that the ApplicationPoolIdentity is a virtual, local account for each application pool which is not part of the SAM database. So some applications refuse to select this accounts.

Note also that old, discontinued IIS releases did not provide the ApplicationPoolIdentity feature.